# How do I bind Control-Home in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I'd like to bind Control-Home to put the cursor at the first line of the file.
I've tried the following options in my .emacs file, but none of them work.

```
(global-set-key "\C-<home>" 'beginning-of-buffer)
(global-set-key (kbd "\C-<home>") 'beginning-of-buffer)                                                                     
(global-set-key "\C-^[OH" 'beginning-of-buffer)                                                                             
(global-set-key [C-home] 'beginning-of-buffer)                                                                    
(global-set-key [(control home)] 'beginning-of-buffer)
```

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Try `M-x global-set-key RET C-<home> beginning-of-buffer RET` then see with `M-x repeat-complex-command` what the corresponding Lisp looks like.

Comment: Both `[C-home]` and `[(control home)]` work for me, using "GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (i686-pc-cygwin, GTK+ Version 3.6.4) of 2013-03-11 on fiona".  What version of emacs are you using (`M-x emacs-version`)?

Comment: @tripleee When I try the manual method of entering the command, it seems that the Control key doesn't register at all, only the Home key does (i.e. it says "Set key <home> to command").  It DOES register for other keys, e.g. Control-P.  Also, 'repeat-complex-command' doesn't display any Lisp for me; it just repeats the command.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield I have GNU Emacs 23.1.1 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.18.9) of 2012-03-01 on c6b18n3.bsys.dev.centos.org

Comment: You can see the Lisp by pressing the Up key in the minibuffer at the `repeat-complex-command` prompt; sorry for failing to detail this.

Comment: Ah, I see.  That returns (global-set-key (quote [home]) (quote beginning-of-buffer))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with VirtualBox, running Ubuntu as a VM on a Windows host.  I've reopened a ticket for the issue.  https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/7065

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to figure out what syntax to use is to use the `kbd` macro you tried using, along with the built in help.

Try <kbd>C-h k C-Home</kbd> (or <kbd>M-x describe-key C-Home</kbd>), and look at the buffer that pops up.  For me, it shows:

```
<C-home> runs the command beginning-of-buffer, which is an interactive
compiled Lisp function in `simple.el'.
```

There you see the string `<C-home>`, and that is what you can use to plug into the `kbd` macro.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-home>") 'beginning-of-buffer)
```